# Adding values to map from other map in DART

Tags: dart

I have a map like this

```
Map<String, bool> siSelectedDef = {"1": true, "2": true, "3": false};
```

I want to loop through the map and check for the key which has a value true, and I want to add those keys inside a `List<Map<String, Object>> must`

i.e
 must contains

```
[
{
"si" : "1"
},
{
"si" : "2"
}
]
```

can anyone help me in this, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = {'a': true, 'b': false, 'c': true};

List<Map<String, dynamic>> _list = [];

data.forEach((key, value) {
  if (value) {
    _list.add({'si': key});
  }
});

print(_list);
```

please check [official doc](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/Map-class.html) for more detailed info and other stuffs you can do with Map